# How to parse the uploaded apk file with Java code?

Tags: android, parsing, google-play, apk

I want to know how to implement java code to parse the apk file, get the android application version number and so on, such as after you uploaded android application in Android Market, it will get the version number, permissions.

Anyone can give me idear? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to https://github.com/xiaxiaocao/apk-parser, which is a pure java apk-parser implementation.

Comment: Is there any such solution that has InputStream as a parameter instead of a File or file-path, and still returns the various information about the app (app-icon, app-name , package-name, version-code, version-name...) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA); 
version = pInfo.versionName.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My meaning is access AndroidManifest.xml form Android platform. Such as a web project.

Comment: The PackageInfo object should have all the information in the Manifest file. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html

Comment: did u get ur answer? If so post it.

Answer (score -1):

Though the question is quite outdated, I add my solution here for people looking for howtos.

You can use 
`aapt dump badging abc.apk` to dumpp version code, pacakge name, etc information under command line. Then you can use Java to create a process, execute the command, and get the output of the command as a String.

You know how to do the following things. Use regex to parse the output and get the data you need.